# Valid parameters for canvas.toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Today, I saw this article on Twitter about getting Webm data from a canvas:
http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/31486670538/creating-webm-video-from-getusermedia

He uses "image/webp" as a parameter to `canvas.toDataURL();`

I know that you can pass `image/jpeg` and `image/png` but are there are more than that?

I have tried searching for this, but cant find a list

Thanks
AH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement).

Chrome supports the `image/webp` type.